# POST de angular para ASP.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Preciso fazer um POST após um click de um botão, para que esse POST ative um método em um controller MVC, estava testando da seguinte forma:

```
[HttpPost]
public void GerarPDF()
{
    string teste = "teste";
}
```

O nome do Controller é ItemController, ja no botão eu coloquei la o ng-click com a função do angular:

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="exibiritem()" class="navbar-btn btn btn-modal"  style="margin-right:0px;" id="btnExibir">
  <center>Exibir</center>
</button>
```

E no controller do angular:

```
function exibiritem(){
    $http({
        url: "/item/GerarPDF",
        method: "POST"
    )};
}
```

Só que não estou conseguindo fazer com que a função no controller do MVC seja executada.Se alguém puder me ajudar, ficaria muito grato, pois meu conhecimento em angular ainda é bem básico.

Comment: Começando pelo começo, a função `exibirItem()` está sendo chamada no clique do botão?

Comment: isso ng-click="exibirItem()"

Comment: Talvez ajude. Exemplo de Post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32026618/angular-http-post-with-asp-net-mvc Exemplo de Get:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37844205/read-the-returned-json-data-from-mvc-controller-in-angular-controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public JsonResult GerarPDF(Objeto objeto) {
    return Json(ObjetoRetorno, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }



$scope.exibiritem= function (objetoEntrada) {
    $http.post('Area/Controller/Action', { objeto: objetoEntrada}).success(function (retorno) {
       $scope.retorno = retorno;
    });
};
```